# Uniqueness Proof for solution to $\nabla^2 G(\textbf{r}) = \delta(\textbf{r})$ with $G \rightarrow 0$ when $|\textbf{r}| \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, infinity

I'm having difficulty understanding the derivation of solution to this equation: $\nabla^2 G (\textbf{r}) = \delta(\textbf{r})$ with $G \rightarrow 0$ when $|\textbf{r}| -> \infty$ in $R^n$ where the boundary condition is defined at infinity.

I suppose that a reasonable approach is to first guess a solution and prove the uniqueness of it, so here's what I've tried to prove the uniqueness:

Assume that $G_1, G_2$ are different solutions, take $G' = G_1 - G_2$ then $\nabla^2 G' = 0$. My purpose is to prove $G' = 0$.

Consider $\int (\nabla G')^2 d^n{\textbf{r}}$ where $d^n{\textbf{r}} \stackrel{\Delta}{=} dV$ is the volume element. In a FINITE space $\Omega$ containing the origin with boundary condition $G'(\textbf{r}) = 0$ when $\textbf{r} \in \partial \Omega$ I can have

$\int_{\Omega} (\nabla G')^2 \cdot dV = \int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (G' \cdot \nabla G') \cdot dV - \int_{\Omega} G' \cdot \nabla^2 G' \cdot dV = \int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (G' \cdot \nabla G') \cdot dV$

and by divergence theorem

$\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (G' \cdot \nabla G') \cdot dV = \int_{\partial \Omega} (G' \cdot \nabla G') \cdot \textbf{n}(\textbf{r}) \cdot dS = 0$

where $\textbf{n}(\textbf{r})$ is the norm vector of surface element on $\partial \Omega$. Thus $\nabla G' = 0$ in $\Omega$ and $G' = 0$ in $\Omega$.

However when the boundary condition involves $|\textbf{r}| \rightarrow \infty$ I'm not sure whether the step at which I applied divergence theorem is still valid.

Any help is appreciated :)

**Edited:**

$\delta(\textbf{r})$ here is the Dirac Delta function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use the following argumentation:

Let $B_R =\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n | ||x||\leq R \}$ be a ball of size $R$. Let $\phi_R\in C_0^\infty(B_R)$ with $\phi_R(0)\not = 0$ be arbitrary.
Then from $G(r)=\delta(r)$, we get
\begin{align}
&\langle \nabla^2 G,\phi_R\rangle_{B_R} = \langle \delta,\phi_R\rangle_{B_R}=\phi_R(0)\\
\Leftrightarrow&\langle \nabla G,\nabla \phi_R\rangle_{B_R}=-\phi_R(0) \quad \quad \quad (*)
\end{align}
Now $G'=G_1-G_2$ are all three supposed to be solutions and $G_1\not \equiv G_2$. Further note, that $G'\equiv 0$ is not a solution. Then $(*)$ is true for $G'$, i.e.
\begin{align}
&\langle \nabla G',\nabla \phi_R\rangle_{B_R}=-\phi_R(0) \\
\Leftrightarrow& \langle \nabla G_1,\nabla \phi_R\rangle_{B_R}
-\langle \nabla G_1,\nabla \phi_R\rangle_{B_R}=-\phi_R(0)
\end{align}
But since $G_1$ is a solution and $(*)$ has to hold,
\begin{align}
&\langle \nabla G_2,\nabla \phi_R\rangle_{B_R}=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow & \langle \nabla^2 G_2, \phi_R\rangle_{B_R}=0
\end{align}
Since $\phi_R$ was arbitrary, by the fundaental theorem of variational calculus
\begin{align}
\nabla^2G_2 \equiv 0
\end{align}
has to hold. This means, that $G_2$ is linear in $r$ independent of $B_R$. But since $G\rightarrow 0$ for $|r|\rightarrow \infty$ we have $G_2\equiv 0$ which is a contradiction because the solution is not identically zero. $\blacksquare$

**EDIT:**

1)
$C^\infty_0(B_R)$ is the set of all functions that are differentiable of arbitrary order (that's what $\infty$ refers to) and have compact support on the set $B_R$, i.e. for $\phi \in C^\infty_0(B_R)$, we have $\phi(x)=0,\forall x \not \in B_R$

2) First, I assumed $\delta(r)$ is the [Dirac delta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), which has the property, that $\int f(x)\delta(x)\,dx = f(0)$ which explains the right side of the equation for $(*)$. The notation $\langle f,g \rangle_{B_R}$ simply means the scalar product $\int_{B_R}f(x)g(x)\, dx$. Thus \begin{align}
\langle \nabla^2g,\phi \rangle_{B}&=\int_B \nabla^2 g(x)\phi(x)\,dx
\\&{}^*=[\nabla g \phi]_{\partial B}-\int_B \nabla g(x)\nabla\phi(x)\,dx
\end{align}
where we use integration by parts at $*$. The first term $[\nabla g \phi]_{\partial B}=0$ because $\phi(x)=0 \forall x\in \partial B$

**2nd EDIT:**

Let me give this one last try. I'll keep the fist part, i.e. $\langle \nabla G,\nabla \phi\rangle = -\phi(0)$

Now if $G$ is not a unique solution, then there exists another solution $G'\not \equiv G$. Then $G'=G+H$ with $H\not \equiv 0$. However, $H$ does not have to be a solution. Since $G'$ and $G$ are solutions, we have
\begin{align}
 -\phi(0)&= \langle \nabla G',\nabla \phi\rangle \\
&= \langle \nabla G,\nabla \phi\rangle+ \langle \nabla H,\nabla \phi\rangle \\
&=-\phi(0)+ \langle \nabla H,\nabla \phi\rangle
\end{align}
So we get
\begin{align}
\langle \nabla H,\nabla \phi\rangle=0
\end{align}
Again with integration by party and the fundamental lemma of variational calculus, $H$ has to be linear in $r$. **Assume** now $H$ is **not** zero , i.e. $H\not \equiv 0$. Then $H$ is either constant $\not = 0$ or linear with slope $\not = 0$
Since we know, that $G(r)=0$ for $r\rightarrow \infty$, we know that $G(r)+H(r)=H(r)$ for $r \rightarrow \infty$. But $H(r)\not =0 $ for $r \rightarrow \infty$ since it is either constant $\not = 0$ or linear. But then $G'(r)=G(r)+H(r)\not = 0$ for $r \rightarrow \infty$. Which means that $G'$ can't be a solution. This is a contradiction, so $H\equiv 0$ and thus $G'\equiv G$, thus the solution is unique.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However I'm so sorry that since not being familiar with your notations I can't understand your solution. Would you please explain or refer to some book/website for: 1. $C_0^{\infty}$ 2. derivation of (*) like how do you define $<\nabla G_1, \nabla \phi_R>$, is it convolution $(\nabla G_1 * \nabla \phi_R)(\textbf{r})$ in $B_R$ ?

Comment: I guess you refer to the $\langle ...\rangle$ notation?

$\langle f,g \rangle_B =\int_B f(x)g(x) dx$, it is just the scalar product.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation, just at some points I guess you might have typos. Do you mean (*) = $[\nabla g(x) \phi(x)]_{\partial B} - \int_{B} \phi(x) \nabla^2 g(x) dx = - \phi(0)$ by "integral by parts"? If not I'm afraid that there's still something unclear to me.

Comment: I'm sorry for all typos, if you point out where I've done them, I will fix them. By (*) inside the edit I mean: integral by parts / integration by parts to basically show
$\int_B g'' \phi dx = [g'\phi]_{\partial B} - \int_B g'\phi' dx$

Comment: Oh sure it was my fault, I misunderstood your meaning of the * sign.

Comment: Brilliant!  Seems I can't raise a question about the 2nd edition now,  let me double check it and I will mark it as solved later :)

Answer (score 0):

@sonystarmap, I think I get the idea now: you denote $G'=G_1 - G_2$, a sphere $B_R$ with radius $R$ and functions

$$\phi_R(\textbf{r}) = \{ {\begin{array}{cc} arbitrary & |\textbf{r}| < R \\ 0 & \textbf{r} \ge R \end{array}} $$

Then with $\langle \nabla G', \nabla \phi_R \rangle_{B_R}=\langle \nabla G_1, \nabla \phi_R \rangle_{B_R}=-\phi_R(\textbf{0})$ got (ignoring the intermediate reasoning) $\nabla^2 G_2 \equiv 0$, is it?

In my calculation $\langle \nabla G', \nabla \phi_R\rangle_{B_R}=0$, because $\nabla^2 G'=\nabla^2 G_1 - \nabla^2 G_2 = 0$ and $\langle \nabla G', \nabla \phi_R\rangle_{B_R} = \int_{\partial B_R} \nabla G' \cdot \phi_R \cdot d\textbf{S} - \int_{B_R} \nabla^2 G' \cdot \phi_R \cdot d\Omega = 0$.

So $\langle \nabla G', \nabla \phi_R \rangle_{B_R} = -\phi_R(\textbf{0})$ doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Exactly, I wanted to show $\nabla^2 G_2 \equiv 0$.

I think the reason for our different result for $\langle \nabla G', \nabla \phi\rangle$ is that I want to use a proof by contradiction. **If** $G'\not \equiv 0$ is a solution of the problem, it should fulfill that $\langle \nabla G', \nabla \phi\rangle=-\phi(0)$ which yields a contradiction.

Comment: Yes but even if $G' \not\equiv 0$ is **assumed**, that $G' = G_1 - G_2$ is **by definition**. Hence I would say once you define $G_1$ and $G_2$ to be two solutions to the equation and $G' = G_1 - G_2$ you immediately have $\langle \nabla G', \nabla \phi_R \rangle_{B_R} = 0$ regardless of the **assumption** of $G' \not\equiv 0$, right?

Comment: I get your point, however, I don't see the error in my analysis yielding to the difference. I will take my time to look through everything.

Comment: I think, the problem is, that you assume that the differential equation is linear. But if we rewrite $\nabla^2 G = \delta$ as $L(G,r):=\nabla^2G(r) -\delta(r)$ (which should be zero) we see, that $L(G1+G2,r) \not = L(G1,r)+L(G2,r)$. Now you argue, that since $G1$ and $G2$ are solutions of $L=0$, also $G1-G2$ has to be a solution of $L=0$ which isn't true since $L$ is not linear. In my proof, I also use $G'=G1-G2$, but I don't assume, that the differential operator is linear. I only assume, that the scalar product is linear, which it is. What do you think?

Comment: You say "because $\nabla^2G'=\nabla^2G1-\nabla^2G2=0$" you end up with $<\nabla G',\nabla \phi>=0$. This might be true, but then $G'$ is **by your construction** not a solution of the problem because: $\nabla^2G=\nabla^2G1-\nabla^2G2=\delta-\delta = 0\not \equiv \delta$ which was your original equation. I suppose, that this is the error in your argumentation. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Uhm... I'm not sure if I implied that $G_1 - G_2$ is also a solution to the equation but I didn't assume that. In fact I didn't understand this sentence well "Now $G′=G1−G2$ are all three supposed to be solutions and $G_1 \not\equiv G_2$. Further note, that $G' \equiv 0$ is not a solution." As you already stated that if $G_1, G_2$ are 2 different solutions to the equation then $G' = G_1 - G_2$ cannot be a solution, then why did you get $\langle \nabla G', \nabla \phi_R \rangle_{B_R} = -\phi_R(\textbf{0})$ ?

Comment: I gave it one last try with my 2nd edit, I feel like this is working. Otherwise I'll give up.

Comment: It's fine, the only important stuff is to get things right :)